# Can I STILL submit a new Windows Phone 7.0 app to the MarketPlace?

Tags: windows-phone-7

This has been asked before but long long time ago and things change...

Can I ... blah blah blah read the title.

I hope the answer is no :) so I can tell my client that we can't do a 7.5 -> 7.0 port of their app instead of wasting hours and hours explaining him why it doesn't have any use for it.

Answer (score 0):

No,  you cannot. And what's more, it doesn't make sense, because WP 7.0 can't install apps from the store anymore. Update in obligatory in order to  be able to install apps:

> If you don’t update to Windows Phone 7.5, you’ll still be able to
>   browse Marketplace. But you’ll get an error message if you try to
>   install an app or game, or update one already on your phone.

Source: http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/windowsphone/archive/2012/04/24/two-marketplace-changes-and-how-they-affect-you.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is still possible to submit an app for 7.0 but even if it is possible, nobody would be able to download the app on 7.0 because  it's [not possible to download app for the marketplace if you are still on 7.0.](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/windowsphone/archive/2012/05/22/starting-today-you-need-windows-phone-7-5-to-use-marketplace.aspx)